# What's the word for someone who doesn't appreciate what he has and wants more? - Not a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicates

[What's the word for someone who doesn't appreciate what he has and wants more?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395629/whats-the-word-for-someone-who-doesnt-appreciate-what-he-has-and-wants-more?noredirect=1#comment938107_395629)

> What's the word for someone who is ungrateful/ not appreciative of the things he has but wants more lavish things? For example, instead of appreciating the little things he has in his life, someone might go on and on, complaining about things like how the scratch on his brand new shoe ruined his day or who wants a new car while complaining about his old one.

is erroneously connected as a duplicate to [A single word for someone who is not pleased no matter how hard you try](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/a-single-word-for-someone-who-is-not-pleased-no-matter-how-hard-you-try).

> I'm looking for a word that means someone (especially a boss) who is not pleased (with your work, attitude etc.) no matter how hard you try.

The former is related to never being satiated with what you have. The later is never being satisfied by what other people have done. While there are overlapping themes, the answers provided in the later questions are not suitable for the former. There is a clear distinction between these two concepts.

Comment: I agree. The first question is about consumption, the second about trying to impress someone. They do both share the idea of 'unsatisfiable' but may have different expressions.

Comment: The question has been re-opened. Now someone go answer it!

Comment: Thanks for your help in reopening this question.